# Disable hyphenation in apa6e's footnotes

Tags: footnotes, hyphenation, apa-style, endnotes, ragged2e

I would like to disable hyphenation in apa6e's footnotes, to match APA's 6th edition guidelines.

[apa6e](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa6e) uses ragged2e, and the [ragged2e documentation (pdf)](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/ms/ragged2e.pdf) claims that certain commands can make hyphenation "almost impossible":

```
\setlength{\RaggedLeftRightskip}{0pt plus 1fil}
\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{0pt plus 1fil}
```

These commands disable hyphenation in the body, but not in the (endnotes) footnotes.

How can I either (1) disable ragged2e's hyphenation in apa6e, or (2) edit apa6e.cls to stop using ragged2e altogether?

Example:

```
\documentclass[endnotes]{apa6e}
\title{}
\author{}
\shorttitle{}
\authornote{}

\setlength{\RaggedLeftRightskip}{0pt plus 1fil}
\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{0pt plus 1fil}

\begin{document}

The body does not have any hyphenation. Good. Even
reallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallylongwords remain
unhyphenated.\ 
%
\footnote{However, the footnotes become hyphenated. The
reallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallylongwords become
hyphenatated.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: be careful -- if you have any really, Really, REALLY long words, they may be longer than your line.  (probably not a real concern in english and a wide-ish text width, but if you get into german or some other agglutinative languages, or maybe organic chemistry, you could find yourself with some real problems.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can patch the command that formats the endnote to add `\RaggedRight` to it.  The easiest way to do this is with the `etoolbox` package, using the `\appto` macro, which appends code to an existing macro.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\enoteformat}{\RaggedRight}
```

Here's your sample document:

```
\documentclass[endnotes]{apa6e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\title{}
\author{}
\shorttitle{}
\authornote{}
\setlength{\RaggedLeftRightskip}{0pt plus 1fil}
\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{0pt plus 1fil}

% Add \RaggedRight to the \enoteformat command (from the endnotes package)
\apptocmd{\enoteformat}{\RaggedRight}{}{}
\begin{document}

The body does not have any hyphenation. Good. Even
reallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallylongwords remain
unhyphenated.\ 
%
\footnote{However, the footnotes become hyphenated. The
reallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallylongwords become
hyphenatated.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case, the simpler `\appto` command also works. I've update the answer to reflect this. (There's no real difference between the two in this case.)

Comment: The difference between `\appto` and `\apptocmd` is that the latter applies also to command with mandatory arguments. The extra work of `\apptocmd` is not needed when the command has no arguments. However `\apptocmd` *doesn't* work on commands with an optional argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{originalparameters}{ragged2e}% for the body
\documentclass[endnotes]{apa6e}
\makeatletter% for the footnotes
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\def\apaSIXe@hasendnotes\relax{}\endnote{\raggedright#1}}
\makeatother
\title{}
\author{}
\shorttitle{}
\authornote{}
\begin{document}

The body does not have any hyphenation. Good. Even
reallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallylongwords remain
unhyphenated.\ 
%
\footnote{However, the footnotes become hyphenated. The
reallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreallylongwords become
hyphenatated.}

\end{document}
```